# mysql join and fetch

Tags: mysql, xml, join

I have try to search topic and try all the way I know to settle this problem, but unfortunately I still cannot.

I am now want including some value inside the google maps infowindows.
I found some source from google developer, but now I need to combine 2 table's info and generate a xml for google maps case.

Table1

```
id    |    tid    |   hotelprice   |  attachment
1          234          100             http://xxx.xxx.xxx
2          345          106             null
3          663          905             null
```

Table2

```
name    |    url    |  description   | lat  | lng    | type  | area
ABC          111       lorumop111      2.12   -109.1   poi     us
EFG          234       lorumop234      2.13   -109.2   hotel   us
HIJ          345       lorumop345      2.14   -109.2   hotel   us
```

I need to output the value as XML, first I query

```
$queryprice = mysql_query("SELECT t1.tid, t2.url, t1.hotelprice 
                           FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.url = t1.tid;");
```

after that I also query

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE area = '".$area."'");
```

after that I need to use the source to output as XML,

```
while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) && ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($queryprice))){
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("description", $row['description']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("url", $row['url']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("area", $row['area']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("hotel_bookingprice", $row2['hotelprice']);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

but when output as XML, the hotelprice is incorrect.

```
<markers>
<marker name="ABC" lat="2.12" lng="-109.1" type="poi" description="lorumop111" url="111" area="us" hotelprice="NOT correct amount even this amount can't found in this table, this should be 0 or null because t1 don't have tid=111"/>
<marker name="EFG" lat="2.13" lng="-109.2" type="hotel" description="lorumop234" url="234" area="us" hotelprice="NOT correct amount"/>
</markers>
```

what I need is:

```
<marker name="ABC" lat="2.12" lng="-109.1" type="poi" description="lorumop111" url="111" area="us" hotelprice="0"/>
<marker name="EFG" lat="2.13" lng="-109.2" type="hotel" description="lorumop234" url="234" area="us" hotelprice="100"/>
<marker name="HIJ" lat="2.14" lng="-109.3" type="hotel" description="lorumop345" url="345" area="us" hotelprice="106"/>
```

I hope your guy can understand what I say, thank you.

Comment: I think you should use two separate while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT t2.*, t1.hotelprice FROM t2 
                          LEFT JOIN t1 ON t2.url = t1.tid
                      WHERE area = '".$area."'");

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) ){
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("description", $row['description']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("url", $row['url']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("area", $row['area']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("hotel_bookingprice", $row['hotelprice']);
}
```

Comment: if I would like to join three table, how?if I try:

$query = mysql_query("SELECT t2.*, t1.hotelprice, t3.views FROM t2 
                          LEFT JOIN t1,t3 ON t2.url = t1.tid = t3.tid
                      WHERE area = '".$area."'");

will show error

Comment: `SELECT t2.*, t1.hotelprice FROM t2 
                          LEFT JOIN t1 ON t2.url = t1.tid                           LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.url = t3.tid
                      WHERE area = '".$area."'`